# Route to a specific controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter for the back end of my website.
For that I have created admin folder inside my controller.
My issue is that when i type the url

> http://localhost/varma/admin

It should redirect to the file login.php which is inside the contollers/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the routes.php write this code:

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/controller/function';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your routes.php file ,

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/login/your_login_function_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

$route['admin']='admin/login';

where login the is login function name